# How to upload data from csv to database(PostgreSQL) on python

Tags: python, database, postgresql, csv, sqlalchemy

I have a few parsers that collect data and make csv file, after collecting data I need to upload data from csv to my database(PostgreSQL)

p.s.table in database is already exist and just need to append data

How can I do this?

I have try to use sqlalchemy, but after connection don't know what to do

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:username@localhost:5432/DB_name')
```

Didn't find information that could help me

Comment: You need to [insert](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are learning, because you didn't check the google before.
I recommand to study the following:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/data_insert.html#tutorial-core-insert

So basically you have to do something like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import insert
import csv

with open('names.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        insert('user_table').values(name=row['name'], fullname=row['fullname'])
```

Then commit!

Good luck!